# Are elements of @_ reused for new subroutine call or new @_ is created?

Tags: perl, debugging

I suppose it is depend on context.

1. It is reused when `&func` call is made
2. It is created for all other calls

I have [this code](https://github.com/KES777/Devel-DebugHooks/blob/develop/lib/Devel/DebugHooks.pm#L1004) where **I got unexpected `eval` call** at line 1004:

```
sub save_context {
    @DB::context =  ( \@_, (caller 2)[8..10], $@, $_ );  # line 1004
    print_state "\nTRAPPED IN  ", "\n\n"   if _ddd;
    DB::state( 'inDB', 1 );
}
```

And this stacktrace:

```
DB /x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm 1419 DB::orig_frames 
DB /x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm 1460 DB::push_frame 
DB /x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm 1004 DB::__ANON__[/x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm:1460] 
DB /x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm 1004 (eval) 
DB /x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm 1251 DB::save_context 
DB /x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm 1288 DB::DB_my 1
MyApp::Controller::User /x/lib/MyApp/Controller/User.pm 41 DB::DB 1
Mojolicious /x/local/lib/perl5/Mojolicious.pm 133 MyApp::Controller::User::list 
Mojolicious::Plugins /x/local/lib/perl5/Mojolicious/Plugins.pm 15 Mojolicious::__ANON__[/x/local/lib/perl5/Mojolicious.pm:133] 
...
```

From my log file I can see that `DBIx::Class::DESTROY` sub is called:

```
DB::sub  DB::state: l:1 d:0 s:5 t:0  /x/local/lib/perl5/Devel/DebugHooks.pm:1004  -->  DBIx::Class::DESTROY
```

**Why object destruction is postponed?** I suppose that is related to `@_` in some way

Any suggestions appreciated about that what may trigger object destruction here

Comment: Is DESTROY being called at the end of the script (global destruction phase)?

Comment: @mob I have found why `DESTROY` is called. See answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `&func` call without an argument list, not only are the elements of `@_` reused, the whole `@_` is reused.

```
sub main {
    print "main: @_ is ", \@_, "\n";
    func(@_);  # Values from @_ are copied into new @_. @_ after call: 1 2 3
    &func;     # Origin @_ is passed down.           So @_ after call: 2 3
}

sub func {
    print "func: @_ is ", \@_, "\n";
    shift @_;  # Here @_ is modified. Pay attention what values @_ left after call
}

main(1,2,3);  # @_ will be initialized by: 1 2 3
```

Typical output:

```
main: @_ is ARRAY(0xfc5958)
@_ initial: 1 2 3
func: @_ is ARRAY(0xfc5a00)
@_ after func(): 1 2 3
func: @_ is ARRAY(0xfc5958)
@_ after &func: 2 3
```

Going from `main` into the `&func` call, `@_` is not localized, copied, or changed in any way. Altering `@_` inside `func` from a `&func` call affects `@_` in the caller, but altering it from a `func()` call does not.

Comment: I understand what is coming on from `Typical output` but your explanation is not clear

Comment: @Engen Konkov, Explaining from the other direction, `&$func(LIST)` is equivalent to `do { local @_; alias push @_, LIST; &$func }`

Answer (score 2):

I have found why `DESTROY` is called while assigning:

1. The old `@DB::context` items are destroyed
2. Where first item is `ARRAYREF` to subroutine arguments `LIST`
3. When this item is destroyed there is no more links to arguments, they are destroyed

Because of those links arguments are not destroyed when they should normally. Example:

```
{                                             #1
my $handle = DBI->connect(...);               #2
some_sub_call( 'arg', $handle, 1, 2, ... );   #3
}                                             #4
another_call( a => 1 );                       #5
```

1. Here is some scope
2. `$handle` should be destroyed at the end of scope
3. When **this call is made under debugger** the link to `@_` is stored at `@DB::context`
4. The end of scope. `$handle` is not destroyed because it still referred
5. Another subroutine call. Old values of `@DB::context` are freed. So `$handle` destrucion is postponed until this

So `@_` is not guilty. Thank you @mob for your explanation